# Stored Procedure not giving expected results in Insert query

Tags: mysql, syntax, insert

I have a product table and a product varieties table.

```
**Product Table**
pid
articlenum
desc
price

**Product Varities Table**
pvid,
sizeid,
materialid,
pid fk
quantity
barcode
```

I am creating an Interface where a user can ADD a new product, I have a stored proc, with two statements. First will execute insert into product table and the other into product varieties table.

Issue I have is, how do I insert a product id into product varieties table using the article id - each article can have multiple varieties such as s, m, l, xl, xs?

Using the code below, I cannot do that because it returns more than one record on select for each article.

```
INSERT INTO product 
  (articlenum,pdesc,price) 
VALUES 
  (articlenum, pdesc,price);

set @productid = select DISTINCT product.product_id 
  from product 
  where product.articlenum = articlenum;

INSERT INTO product_varities
  (sizeid,materialid,pid,quantity,barcodevalue) 
VALUES 
  (sizeid, materialid, @productid, quantity, barcode);
```

Tried:

```
set @productid = select product.pid 
  from product 
  where product.articlenum = articlenum;
```

This returns result like:

```
PID
1
2
3
```

Required Result:

```
PID
1
```

If I am unclear, please ask.

Comment: use `last_insert_id()` to get the id of the new record. what you're doing is subject to race conditions. there is **NO** guarantee that another parallel user will insert another record between the time you `insert` and then `select`, meaning you'd get that OTHER user's id, not the one you just created.

Comment: aah that totally skipped my mind!, the idea is the only one user will be able to to this insert anway, but is there a way to avoid what you just mentioned?

Comment: that's what last_insert_id() is for. the ID created by the last insert that YOU performed on THIS particular database connection. it won't report an ID from some other user or other connection.

Comment: @MarcB , make that an answer :)

Comment: this line "set @productid = select product.pid from product where product.articlenum =   articlenum;" is not good. you need replace the second  articlenum with your values

Comment: use "limit" for display one record like select product.pid 
  from product 
  where product.articlenum = articlenum LIMIT 1;